# Running time complexity of double for-loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm somewhat confused by the following algorithms. In particular, I don't understand why the first is O(n) and the second is O(n^2). My only intuition is perhaps that the inner and outer loops for the first algorithm aren't "linked." Secondly, I can intuitively see that the second algorithm is O(n^2), but how would we go about finding some constants c1, c2 to prove f(n) is big-0 and little-0 of n^2?

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    sum++;
```

---

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sum++;
```

Comment: If those are nested for loops in the first algorithm, that is not `O(n)` but `O(n^2)`

Comment: Ok interesting - maybe my professor made a mistake in his answer key then

Comment: the first one looks like it's O(n^2), and the second one looks like O(n*m)

Comment: @user2485710 Well, for m = n.

Comment: @delnan yeah, but it's a really weird loop, maybe it's one the pitfalls/traps that a teacher really wants to offer to his students.

Comment: Second one is also `O(n^2)` - [see the first formula here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

Comment: So if I want to show that f(n) is bigO and littleO of n^2, what should I choose for my f(n)? Would it be (n)(n+1)/2 for the first?

Comment: Aside from the indenting on `sum++`, they look the same to me.

Comment: @SamIam The condition of the inner loop differs - `j < i` versus `i < n`.

Comment: @user2485710 While I suppose that's technically possible, it's a wholly unorthodox approach and does not teach any useful skills. This is *not* a trap that happens in real algorithm analysis, because real algorithms don't contain no-op loops. Therefore I suggest it's an meaningless typographical oddity.

Comment: All hail the curly braces! If indentation `does matter`, the first loop will be `no-op`, so if we `don;t count it`, then the first example will be O(n)

Comment: Both of them are O(n^2). The first one executes for n^2 times and the second one for 1+2+3+..n = n*(n+1)/2 times. So both have the same time complexity in terms of Big O, i.e O(n^2).

Comment: OP, could you please clarify whether the different indentation of the two `sum++;` statements is from the original assignment, or an accident? It really trips up people.

Comment: Hmm, I typed it as it's shown in the original assignment

Comment: In `C` and in `Java` typed as is, the first algo runs in `O(n^2)` regardless of if `sum++` is under the first loop or second loop. I confirmed by commenting / uncommenting the inner loop. Is your class dependent upon a specific language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those are **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

Your code has a handy mechanism for measuring the time complexity, and that is the `sum` variable

Go implement that with different values for `n`.  if your `sum`s make a line, it's linear.  if they don't it's not linear.   I think that you'll find that in your first algorithm, `sum` will always be exactly `n^2`

Answer (score 2):

To formally deduce the order of growth, you may proceed like the following:

[image]

For the **c'** case, the inner loop won't execute when `i = 0`, therefore, the solution is to externalize the outer loop "iterations" that won't affect the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Both code blocks represent O(n^2)

1st block should is a typical example of n^2 complexity.  Inner and outter loops are traversing N times.

2nd block is also n^2 even though the inner loop breaks earlier than the 1st block would on small i's.  If you print out the i and j you'll see that this loop represents the combination pairs of i and j ... i.e. (1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2) etc